# Call Android method from HTML always directs to "else"

Tags: javascript, android, html, if-statement

Always shows "else" statement. I don't know that's wrong here. please help.

**The Android code:**

```
public void setResult(final int val,final String cat){
        if(cat=="home")
        {
            counter=0;
        }
        else if(cat=="featured")
        {
            counter=1;
        }
        else if(cat=="editorial")
        {
            counter=2;
        }
        else if(cat=="gallery")
        {
            counter=3;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(parentActivity, "Invalid category: " + cat + "\n" + "cat.toString() is: " + cat.toString(), 5).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this.parentActivity, "Callback got val: " + val + "\n Category is: " + cat, 5).show();
    }
```

**The HTML code (within script tag):**

```
function onload()
{
    window.MyHandler.setResult(2,"featured");
}
```

The output here is:

```
Invalid category: featured
cat.toString() is: featured
Callback got val: 2
Category is: featured
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `equals()` method instead `==`

For example

```
cat.equals("featured");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare Strings like that:

```
if(cat=="home"){...}
```

You have to use the `equals()` method:

```
 if(cat.equals("home")){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

change like this

```
if(cat.equals("home"))
    {
        counter=0;
    }........
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings try this

```
if (cat.equals("home")) {
    counter = 0;
}
```